# Is there any well-documented example code or article about Keychain programming for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, keychain

I've found only this wrapper for the Keychain Services API: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

When you only want to use Keychain, it makes your life easy. But when you want to understand keychain, it's terrible. Not a single useful comment.

Hopefully someone knows a blog post or article that has documented example code?

(the examples from Apple are pretty obfuscated and useless in this regard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this Apple example you will find useful.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html